# Mysql:multiple join in one table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and inside database are table with joins.

My first table is `cardtests` the columns are `id` and `name` only.
I joined it in `tests` my columns are :

> card1_id |  card2_id | card3_id
>
> in which they are equal to cardtests.id.

My sqlquery is

```
SELECT cardtests.name 
  FROM tests 
  JOIN cardtests 
  ON tests.card1_id = cardtests.id
  ON tests.card2_id = cardtests.id
  ON tests.card3_id = cardtests.id
```

But the problem is they are not working just wanted to display all the names of 3 cards. How will i do it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want three joins:

```
Select ct1.name, ct2.name, ct3.name
from tests t left join
     cardtests ct1
     on t.card1_id = ct1.id left join
     cardtests ct2
     on t.card2_id = ct2.id left join
     cardtests ct3
     on t.card3_id = ct3.id;
```

The `left join` simply handles rows where one or more of the card test columns may not be populated.

Often, though, having multiple columns with the same name, only distinguished by a number, is an indication that you should be using a separate table, with one row per tests and card.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select cardtests.name 
from tests 
join cardtests on cardtests.id in (tests.card1_id, tests.card2_id, tests.card3_id)
```